# How to get my datagridview showing live data and format cells based on times

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timer

I have a datagridview that shows a list of all cars in the workshop. To the right of the registration number, is several columns of phases. The duration of each phase for each car has been estimated and next to that I need to show the actual time taken. Ideally this needs to be a live timer ticking away.

[image: Datagrid screenshot]

Each phase for each job can be active, paused or completed.

In terms of the database tables, I have the following -

JobDetails

```
ID - PK Auto increment
JobID - Int (Joined to Jobs table)
PhaseID - String (joined to JobPhases table)
EstimatedTime - decimal
ActualTime decimal
Status int (EntryType - NotStarted, Active, Paused, Complete)
```

JobPhases

```
ID - PK String
Name - VarChar(150)
```

TimeLogs

```
ID int
JobID int
PhaseID string
UserID int
DateEntry datetime
EntryType int
```

What happens is the userid, job number, task id and an action (NotStarted, Active, Pauused and Complete) is scanned through a barcode. This then sets the job as active.

I can set and get the time taken by adding the JobDetail.ActualTime to the TimeLog.LastEntry.DateEntry. The trouble is I need to show this as a live ticker in each cell, or at least roughly 10 second interval refreshes

The code I have so far is -

```
    private void tstbCommand_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            User u = User.FromID(Convert.ToInt32(tstbUser.Text.TrimStart('U')));
            Job j = Job.FromID(Convert.ToInt32(tstbJobNo.Text.TrimStart('E', 'N', 'K', 'J', 'C')));
            JobDetail jd = JobDetail.JobDetailFromJobIDAndPhaseID(j.ID, tstbTaskID.Text.TrimStart('E', 'N', 'K', 'J', 'C', 'D'));
            TimeLog log = new TimeLog();

            switch (tstbCommand.Text)
            {
                case "CMDACTIVE":
                    if (jd.Status == EntryType.Active)
                    {
                        //Alert already active
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("The scanned job is already active.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Ok to update status to active
                        jd.Status = EntryType.Active;
                        log.EntryType = jd.Status;

                        JobPhaseTimer timer = new JobPhaseTimer();
                        timer.UID = jd.ID + "_" + jd.PhaseID;
                        timer.JobDetailID = jd.ID;
                        timer.JobID = j.ID;
                        timer.PhaseID = jd.PhaseID;
                        timer.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                        timer.Stopwatch.Start();
                        timer.Start();
                        timers.Add(timer.UID, timer);

                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("The job " + jd.JobID + " has been set to active by " + u.FullName + ".");
                    }
                    break;
                case "CMDPAUSE":
                    if (jd.Status == EntryType.Paused)
                    {
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("The scanned job is already paused.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JobPhase phase = JobPhase.FromID(jd.PhaseID);
                        jd.Status = EntryType.Paused;
                        log.EntryType = jd.Status;

                        TimeLog lastEntry = TimeLog.GetLastTimeLogEntry(j.ID, jd.PhaseID);
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add(lastEntry.EntryType + ", " + lastEntry.DateEntry);

                        jd.ActualTime = Convert.ToDecimal(jd.ActualTime) + Convert.ToDecimal(DateTime.Now.Subtract(lastEntry.DateEntry).TotalHours);
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("The job phase " + phase.Name + " for job " + jd.JobID + " has been paused by " + u.FullName + ".");
                    }
                    break;
                case "CMDCOMPLETE":
                    if (jd.Status == EntryType.Complete)
                    {
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("The scanned job is already completed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        jd.Status = EntryType.Complete;
                        log.EntryType = jd.Status;
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("The job " + jd.JobID + " has been completed by " + u.FullName + ".");
                    }
                    break;
                case "CMDQC":
                    if (u.MergedRole.HasRight("workshop.QualityCheck"))
                    {
                        if (jd.Status == EntryType.QualityChecked)
                        {
                            lstAlerts.Items.Add("The scanned job has already been quality checked.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            jd.Status = EntryType.QualityChecked;
                            log.EntryType = jd.Status;
                            lstAlerts.Items.Add("The job " + jd.JobID + " has been quality checked by " + u.FullName + ".");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lstAlerts.Items.Add("You do not have sufficient rights to quality check.");
                    }
                    break;
            }

            log.JobID = j.ID;
            log.UserID = u.ID;
            log.PhaseID = jd.PhaseID;

            log.EntryType = jd.Status;
            jd.UpdateJobDetail(u.Username);
            log.AddNewTimeLog();

            tstbJobNo.Text = "";
            tstbUser.Text = "";
            tstbTaskID.Text = "";
            tstbCommand.Text = "";
}
```

To keep the data on the datagridview, at the moment I am calling LoadData() on a timer tick -

```
void LoadData()
    {
        foreach (JobPhaseTimer timer in timers.Values)
        {
            JobDetail jd = JobDetail.JobDetailFromJobIDAndPhaseID(timer.JobID, timer.PhaseID);
            jd.ActualTime = jd.ActualTime + Convert.ToDecimal(timer.Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            jd.UpdateJobDetail("Test");
        }

        dt = JobManager.GetTodaysJobs();

        if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
            dataGridView1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                //access picturebox here#
                dt = JobManager.GetTodaysJobs();
                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
            }));
        else
        {
            //access picturebox here
            dt = JobManager.GetTodaysJobs();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns();
        }
    }
```

Finally, I then must format the cell colour according to the EstimatedTime/ActualTime. If ActualTime (Live) is below EstiamtedTime- green. If ActualTime greater than EstiamtedTime - Red, if Actualime is near (logic not decided on yet), display yellow.

Any thoughts/ideas on how I can achieve the above? I have not done a live datagrid before!

Comment: You know to use a timer and that's the main principle to make a `live` datagridview, your problem seems to be how to format/show your data in `DataGridView` the way you want.

Comment: I guess that's correct, although I have been playing with this since posting and it appears although the timer does what I need, I can't scroll the grid or click any cells before the next refresh takes place and I get sent back to the top.